# Transformation of random variable by normal inverse

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am stuck with the following statement: if $ F_X(x) $ is the distribution function of a random variable $ X $, then get the distribution of $ Y = F_N^{-1}(F_X(X)) $ where $ F_N $ is the distribution function of a $ N(\mu, \sigma) $ variable.

I know some theorems about transformations of random variables. But this statement is overly generic and I can't found anyone working for all the cases: $ X $ can be any random variable; it can be discrete, continuous or both at the same time. We can decompose $ F_X = C_X + D_X $ being $ C_X $ and $ D_X $ the continuous and discrete distribution functions associated with $ X $. But what can I do with $ F_N^{-1} (C_X(X) + D_X(X)) $?

Comment: Start with the distribution of $F_X(X)$.

Comment: $N$ is a continuous distribution. It is well-known and easy to see that when $X$ follows a continuous distribution that $F_X(X)$ is uniform on $[0,1]\,.$ Then $Y$ will normal with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma\,.$ When $X$ is not continuous it looks a bit hairy. In the worst case I would take $X$ being Poisson and look at $Y$ through a simulation.